# Text Transition on Click D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have been searching on the internet for a simple fiddle of taking text with two x y coordinates and transitioning it from point 1 to point 2 but cannot seem to find anything if anyone knows of any examples it would be much appreciated. However on to the main point This first snippet of code successfully plots text at the center of the point.

```
    svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.Name;
   })
   .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "0.5px")
   .style('text-anchor','middle')
   .attr("fill", "black")
```

This transition is an attempt to change the text and transition to new locations

```
    svg.selectAll('text') 
    .on('click', function (d) {

    svg.selectAll("text")
    d3.selectAll("text")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)

    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.newNames;
   })
   .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.xx);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.yy);
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "black")
   })
```

Which does not work and does not show the text but also raises no errors in the console. I have done this before with svg shapes and it works the exact same way but for whatever reason I cant seem to get it to transition with text any help is appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code kinda works, but is a bit strange.  First, your initial font-size of `0.5px` doesn't render for me in chrome.  Second, your transition code has a syntax error in:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
d3.selectAll("text")
```

Third, you should be binding data, then doing the transition and not binding during the transition. Also, if you only want to move the existing text and your data didn't change, why rebind at all? And you certainly don't need to `.enter().append()`.

Here's what I think you are after:

```
 svg.selectAll('text')
  .on('click', function(d) {
    svg.selectAll("text")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.newNames;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.xx;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.yy;
      })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "30px")
      .attr("fill", "black")
  });
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      x: 20,
      y: 20,
      xx: 200,
      yy: 200,
      Name: "Hello",
      newNames: "GoodBye"
    },{
      x: 100,
      y: 20,
      xx: 300,
      yy: 200,
      Name: "Love",
      newNames: "Hate"
    }];

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);

    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.Name;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "14px")
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr("fill", "black");


    svg.selectAll('text')
      .on('click', function(d) {
        svg.selectAll("text")
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.newNames;
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.xx;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.yy;
          })
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", "30px")
          .attr("fill", "black")
      })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I implemented this in my code and I get the values of the text to change but no movement. The main difference is that my code is wrapped inside d3.csv('Data.csv', function (data) {   CODE HERE }  ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NewName' of undefined

Comment: @TylerCowan, that means something is wrong with your data binding and the `d` in `function(d){ return d.NewName }` is not defined.  For me to help you further, you'll need to create a jsFiddle or plnkr.co that reproduces the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815992/multiple-svg-transitions-on-click-d3-js I started a new question with a fiddle @Mark