# multiple SVG transitions on Click D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, css-transitions

I have been working on attempting to load in a csv plot a circle with text in the middle and have a transition run when where the circle and the text change and move location. I continue to get cannot read property of undefined which can be seen in this:

### JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g53p16xa/1/

which oddly enough displays differently than on my computer where I use method:

```
d3.csv('AcreageData.csv', function (data) { CODE HERE }
```

rendered in chrome. I have been able to change the circle location and size through transition, however the text will stay in the same spot can anyone help me out I cant seem to get this to work.

Comment: Could you produce a fully working example - simplying to your exact problem? That JSFiddle doesn't run due to other errors - try and produce an example with a circle that just illustrates your transition issue without all the axis stuff etc in there.

Comment: @Ian https://jsfiddle.net/g53p16xa/3/ Now if I was to go add text which will do the same as the circle and move I will get the error

Comment: I just get a bunch of 404 errors and a circle that doesn't move... ?

Comment: @Ian thats odd.... it works for me? Im using chrome.